# ～したいです。実装方法が分かりません。のような質問

Tags: 討議

質問の敷居の問題にもかかってくるので凄くシビアな問題かと思いますが、

> 「～したいです。よろしくお願いします。」
>   「実装方法が全く分かりません。」

以上のような内容としたいことのみが書かれており、
自身の努力された内容や調査結果などが無い質問に対してです。

問題を他人へ丸投げしているように感じるので、
私はマイナス票とコメントにて対応しております。

ですが以前、似たような質問を見つけ、覗いてみますと
"質問の範囲が広すぎる"と、クローズ票が投じられていました。

その一方で、そのような質問でも回答をつけて頂いている優しい方も見えます。

ここで疑問なのですが、
回答するには1～10まで全文書かないといけない。
問題を丸投げしているような質問に対してはどのような対処をするべきでしょうか？

・マイナス票を投じる
・クローズ票を投じる
・何もせず傍観する
・回答を付けてあげる

参考にさせて頂きますので、どうぞよろしくお願いいたします。

---

**みなさん様々な意見ありがとうございました。**
回答する方々も人間ですので
それぞれのお考えや気持ちに左右される部分もあるかと思います。
ですので、的外れなものかもしれませんが、私なりに考えた結果と致しましては、
「質問の内容の方向性さえ確りしていれば回答が付けられるのでOK」と考えました。
結局のところ「回答者が回答できるか？」「回答が役に立つか？」の2点が揃っていれば、
最低限クローズする必要は無さそうな気がしました。

Comment: 関連する討議として：[「コードが思い浮かびません」という質問はどう聞けばよいですか？ - スタック・オーバーフローMeta](http://meta.ja.stackoverflow.com/q/1688/10492)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

- 一応回答の方向性が見えるものであれば、(改善の指摘を付記した上で)回答します。
- 回答できそうになくても改善されれば回答できそうなものは、極力コメントで改善を促します。
- 回答の方向性も絞れないようなものは、基本放置しています。(大半はこれです)
- 回答しようがないもののなかでも特に「ゴミ」のような回答やコメントを引きつけそうな物はクローズ票にしています。
- 回答がついてしまっているものについて、後からその質問と回答を誰かが見たときに役に立たなそうなものは、それを示すためにマイナス票をいれます。(たいがい先にマイナス票がついているのですが)

基本はどうにか(誰かが)回答できればいいな、でもゴミは減らしたいな、というイメージです。

質問者のレベルさえわかればそれなりに回答の方向性は絞れるもので、「○○言語ならわかるが××言語ではわからない」とか、「Hello, worldまではやりました」でも全然違うのですが。

Answer (score 8):

魚でたとえると、

「こんな魚がほしいです。その魚を僕にください」

って言われてるような気がする（つまりあつかましい）ので、回答しづらくなるのかな～と思います。

なので、そういう場合は魚を与えるのではなく、

「その魚であれば、どこそこに行って、こういうふうにやれば釣れると思います。」

と、魚の捕り方（＝参考になりそうな情報源等）を教えて、まず自分で努力してもらうのがいいかなーと僕は思っています。

あと、頻繁に回答している「エキスパート」のみなさんから見ると、「なんだこいつ、丸投げしやがって」と思うかもしれませんが、全然努力してない「ズボラ人間」ではなく、「本当に何から手を付けたらいいからわからない人」や「試行錯誤はしてるけど上手な質問の仕方がわかってない人」である可能性もあります。

僕の場合、稚拙な質問をしている人は「もしかしたらこの人は中学生ぐらいのプログラミング初心者かもしれない」と考えたりします。
もしそうだとしたら、「丸投げすんな！はい、マイナス！」と突き放すのではなく、「そこはこうしましょう」と魚の捕り方（＝情報源の探し方や上手な質問の仕方）を手ほどきしてあげるのもエキスパートの役目なのかなと思ったりします。
まあ、わかんないですけどね。
質問者が「ズボラな社会人プログラマ」なのか「初心者中学生」なのかは。

僕はこんなふうに対処していますが（あ、全然意味不明な質問はスルーすることも多いです）、みなさんいろんな考え方があるでしょうし、対応は自由だと思います。

Answer (score 7):

割とずぼらな質問でも答えているように自分では思っています。
そして、自分が回答する場合ケースバイケースといえばそれまでなのですが、一番大きな指針は

- その回答を他の誰かが見た時に役にたつのか？

いいじゃないですか、おさぼりでも。別に歯を食いしばってプログラムを書く必要はないし、自分も英語版みてかなり助けられたし、今は聞く側の人もそのうち答える方に回ってくれるでしょう（かなり楽天的）
ただし、自分の前提として職業プログラマとしてコードを書くということはあるので、具体的なFWなどの名前が指定されていて、リファレンス読めばできそうなものはRTFMしてますが。（特に投票行動をするわけではないです）

Answer (score 5):

個人的な行動優先順位は下記の通りです。

1. 何もせず傍観する
2. クローズ票を投じる
3. マイナス票を投じる

参考までに、ヘルプにある[クローズ](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions)と[マイナス投票](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down)の基準を引用します。とはいえ、正直な所、そのときの気分に影響されることは否定しません。

[質問が [クローズ済み] または [改善待ち] とは?](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions)：

> 範囲が広すぎる - 質問に答えるために本がまるまる 1 冊必要だったり、正しい答えがいくつもあったりする場合は、おそらく範囲が広すぎます。
>   考えられる回答が多すぎるか、または良質な回答をしようとすると長くなりすぎてこの形式に収まらないと思われます。回答を絞り込めるように詳細を追加するか、数パラグラフ内に回答が収まるように問題点を分けてください。

[権限 > マイナス投票](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down)：

> どんな時にマイナス投票したらいいですか?
>   はなはだしくずさんな、まったく努力していない投稿、または明らかに、そして危険なほど不正確な回答を見つけたら、マイナス票を使用してください。

---

おことわり：丁寧な回答される方を否定する意図はありません！

> ・回答を付けてあげる

私の場合は、この手の質問に回答する気はありません。

全く分からないという理解レベルの質問者に対して、「○○を実現するには～▲▲と■■をこう組合せて～」という、一つの「意見」を示すことは出来るかも知れません。しかし、限られた質問内容からの推測に基づくアドバイスが、質問者の真の目的にマッチするケースはほとんどないと考えています。また、小問題への分解を自力で行えないレベルにある質問者に対して、こちらから問題の分割案を提示したところで、個別の小問題についてもやはり分からないのではという考えもあります。

Comment: やはり回答者も人間ですから気分によって回答してあげようって気持ちになることはありますよね。それと後半に関しては自分も同意見です。実現したい機能がどのような仕組みで実現できるのか？命令を細分化出来なければ組み上げることはできないですからね。ただコピペするなど鵜呑みにするだけでは身につかないと思います。

Comment: 後半について。　別に「質問者の真の目的」をエスパーしたり、質問者に１つの質問ですべてをわからせてあげたりする必要はないのでは？　このサイトの目標は「プログラミングに関するあらゆる質問の詳細な回答集をみんなで作り上げること」であって質問者に奉仕することではありませんから。　また、たとえ質問者が個別の小問題を直ちに解けずとも、それらが分割されているということは調べる指針を立てる上で非常に有用です（答えのキーワードを知っている人からすれば１度や２度の検索で見つかる情報が、わからない人には数時間掛けても見つからなかったりします！）。

Comment: クローズの基準にもあるようにあまりに絞り込まれていない内容だとすると何処に対し回答をするべきか困ることになります。また、その細分化を回答者が行うと質問者とやり取りすることになります。そのやり取りの上で主題も変わっていってしまうので、結局の所、問題点が始めから見えていないと回答者が何に対して回答していいのか迷ってしまうと思います。

Comment: @user10685 コメント前半には同意です。後半については、1つ上のSiegさんコメントで私が言いたかったことをカバーしています。結局のところ、具体的な解法指針すら無い状態（どうすればいいのかわからない）からスタートした質問では、質問者ー回答者間の細かいやりとりが延々続く傾向にあり、結果的に残った応報履歴はサイト目的にそぐわない（＝クローズに価する）という考え方です。

Answer (score 5):

やりたいことを実現するためのプロセスが全くわからない場合もあるでしょうし、参考にしたサイトの通りにやった（と思った）のにうまく動かない、動くはずなのに！

こういう時は第三者から見た冷静な視点での意見は役に立つことも多いので、一概に切り捨てることはできないですし、質問者当人にしか知り得ない環境の情報などが明示されないこともありますので、「もう少し明確にすると、より正確な回答が得られるかも知れません」と添えることはあります。

もちろん、自分で調べずに何でもかんでも連投してるようなのが見受けられたら、静観するでしょうか。
あくまで私の指針です。

Comment: 調査結果など試行錯誤の後が見えるのであれば、その人の質問の方向性も見えていると思いますし、回答を付ける事も出来るかと思います。やっぱり問題の丸投げが問題なんだと思います。