# プログラミング初学者に対してどのように接するべきでしょうか

Tags: 討議, サポート, 回答の仕方

ときどき、プログラミングを初めたばかりで、繰り返しの制御構文で何が起こるのか分かっていなかったり、条件分岐のイメージがついていなかったりするように見える質問が投稿されることがあります。

たとえば [forの2重ループで行われた演算結果が理解できない](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/73690/19110) から質問文を一部お借りすると、こんな感じです。

> コードを打ち込んだところ、`3,6,9,2,4,6,1,2,3` という回答になりました。
> なぜこうなるか説明することはできません。
> こうなる理由を教えてくれるとありがたいです。
>
> ```
> for (int i = 3; i > 0; i--) {
>   for (int j = 1; j <= 3; j++) {
>     alert(i * j);
>   }
> }
> ```

このような質問に対して、私は戸惑いがちです。まず、どこから説明すれば良いのでしょうか。この質問者さんは構文が分かっていないのか意味論が分かっていないのかどちらでしょう。意味論が分かっていないとして、どう説明すべきでしょうか。

私がよくやるのは「コンピュータの気持ちになって、プログラムがどのように実行されるか紙の上に手で書いてみてください」という形式の回答です。実際に回答の中で途中まで書いてみて、質問者さんにイメージを作ってもらうものです。たとえば [While True: の中に内包されているif文内の　indentationの有無によるerrorが起きる理由が分かりません(無限ループの一種かもしれない)](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/64056/19110) という質問でそのような回答をしてみました。ただこの方法には文字で伝える限界を感じる部分もあり、うまく伝わっているか不安になります（まあ、数打ちゃ当たるの方針で投稿してみるのですが……）。たとえば動画の方が伝わるんじゃないかと思うのですが、動画を作る手間が無視できません。

他の方法として、何が分かっていないのかをコメントで聞いてみるという方法もあります。特に質問者さんが何について質問したいのか混乱なさってそうなとき、内容の整理のためにコメントしてみることがあります。ただ、初学者の場合だとなかなか整理が難しかったり専門用語が通じなかったりするので難しいところです。「自分は何が分かっていないのか」自体が回答になるときすらあります。

また、言葉というのは難しいもので、優しく接するため詳しく説明しているつもりのコメントが長大な厳しい指摘に見えたりし、慣れていない初学者を怯えさせてしまうこともあります（言葉遣いは難しい……）。そうこうしている内に何故かマイナス票がたくさん入って質問者さんが離れてしまうことも、よくあります。

以上のように、私はまだこのような初学者の質問に対する銀の弾丸を持ち合わせていません。コメントを含めた対応から回答を投稿するところまで、一般論としてはどのように行動すれば上手く質問者さんの疑問を解消しやすいのでしょうか。「こういうやり方もある」レベルで構いませんので、皆さんの方法論を伺いたいです。

Answer (score 8):

これは経験則ですが、回答するにあたって「まず、どこから説明すれば良いか？」と悩んでしまうとき、たいていは問題の所在が明らかではなく、回答者により多くの負担がかかっています。このため、まず行う必要があるのは**回答を作成するためにかかる負担を減らす**行動です。

たとえば、質問者へ幾つかのコメントを投げかけ、どこで躓いているのかを特定するために役立つ情報を得ることが出来ます。具体的には次に示すようなコメントが挙げられますが、どのような情報でも良いので、とにかく**問題がどこにあるのかをさらに絞り込む**ことが重要です。

- どこが理解できないか
- どこまでは理解できているか
- そのコードがどのように動作すると考えたか
- 今までに試したことは何か

これにより疑問点がより明確になるため、質問の視認性が向上します。結果としてコメントをすることは、質問者が問題を整理する機会となるだけでなく、他のユーザーが回答するきっかけにもなります。

もうひとつの方法として、インターネット上で類似の問題を探すことが挙げられます。比較的簡単な問題であれば少し検索するだけでも同様の質問が見つかるため、これらを参考に質問者が躓いている箇所を推測し、焦点を絞った回答を作成することが出来ます。この方法は前述のコメントに対して返信が得られなかった場合に行います。

---

ただし、上記の方法は学習を怠る、または問題解決の意思が見られない質問者へは意味をなさない方法であり、そのような質問者に適切な回答をすることは出来ないと思っています。問題を解決するために**ある程度の努力を払わない (またはそれを示さない) ことと、プログラミングの初心者かどうかは無関係**です。そういった意味で、今回のような問題に対する取り組みが明らかではない質問へマイナス投票がされるのは、仕方のないことだと感じます。

一方で、スタック・オーバーフローを利用し始めて日が浅いユーザーに対して、具体的な改善点を述べずに「ちゃんと書いてください」、「質問はしっかり書きましょう」とコメントしたとして、そのコメントの意味を質問者が十分に読み取ってくれるか、というところには疑問があります。もしそれが可能であれば、最初の質問を投稿する前にツアーページやヘルプセンターの幾つかのページを通読し、実践しているでしょう。

> また、言葉というのは難しいもので、優しく接するため詳しく説明しているつもりのコメントが長大な厳しい指摘に見えたりし、慣れていない初学者を怯えさせてしまうこともあります（言葉遣いは難しい……）。

これに関してはあまり有効な予防策が思いつかないですが、質問者の内心としては「コメントの内容はよく読んでいないものの、一度に色々な指摘をされて気圧されてしまっている」という状態なのかな、と推測しています。そこで、「一つのコメントには一つの指摘まで、次の指摘は質問者が対応してから」という風に指摘を小分けにする、などの工夫によって**コメントを質問者が苦痛なく読める長さに抑える**ことで、多少はそういった問題も改善されるのではないかと思います。

Answer (score 3):

ここスタックオーバーフローは、基本的にはユーザ同士の相互扶助の場であるべきです。有償提供に値するコンサルティングや個人指導を求められても、興味を持った回答者の善意や好奇心を別にすれば、誰しもがそれにこたえる義務はないというのが基本スタンスです。

プログラミング初学者（知識の有無） と 質問の初心者（質問スキル） は異なります。残念ながら、スタックオーバーフローは「よりよい質問の仕方」を直接サポートする場ではないでしょう。数をこなすことで質問スキル向上につながるかもしれませんが、これは質問者自身の認識によるところが大きいと思います。問題さえ解決できればよいという質問者に対して、何かを働きかけるのは至難の業です（ましてや無償の互助会において）。

---

> 何が分かっていないのかをコメントで聞いてみるという方法もあります。特に質問者さんが何について質問したいのか混乱なさってそうなとき、内容の整理のためにコメントしてみることがあります。

究極的には、質問自身の内面で本当に聞きたいこと整理してもらうしかないと思います。
質問コメント欄は、このようなケースに対して思考整理を促すコミュニケーションの道具ととらえています。（別手段としてチャットも存在しますが、あまり建設的に使われているのを見たことが無いような...）

> 言葉というのは難しいもので、優しく接するため詳しく説明しているつもりのコメントが長大な厳しい指摘に見えたりし、慣れていない初学者を怯えさせてしまうこともあります（言葉遣いは難しい……）。

文書表現上のテクニックとしては敬体・丁寧語を基本とし、萎縮させないよう情報量をある程度絞って、専門用語から多少かみ砕いた説明を行い、断定的すぎない／やわらかい語尾を選ぶなどがあるとは思います。一方で、こういった表現が小馬鹿にしていると解釈されるリスクもありますし、万人に通じる正解はどこにもないと割り切るべきでしょうね。

> 一般論としてはどのように行動すれば上手く質問者さんの疑問を解消しやすいのでしょうか。

（冷めた意見になってしまいますが）質問者と回答者との相性は誰しもありますから、自分だけで全ケースをケアしようと考えないことも必要だと思います。

supaさん回答にもある通り、この手の質問に丁寧に答えるのは負担が大きく、得てして満足なフィードバックも得られにくいものです。人間であれば気分が良くない日もあり、そのようなときに頑張って回答しようと心をすり減らすより、ほかの誰かに任せる（明日の自分かもしれません:D）ことも大事ではないでしょうか。

Comment: 関連議論：[該当分野では基礎的とされる質問への反応](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1595/), [～したいです。実装方法が分かりません。のような質問](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2036/)